# How to open link from client integrated browser in user's default browser?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

**Scenario:**

Sidebar widget in Lotus Notes client opens XPage from URL configured by widget wizard. This works very well (SSO, speed). Some links in that XPage point to 3rd party web application, which requires much more space. So links have target property set to "_blank" to open in new window, which is still integrated browser of Lotus Notes client. This browser is somewhat crippled, lacks navigation controls, address bar, bookmarks and so on. Users want to launch such link in default browser (IE, FF). This is not XPiNC setup. Browser setting in Location document seems to be ignored.

**Question:**

How to launch link from Notes browser in another browser?
Similar questions posted at this site claim it is not possible with standard browser. I expect Notes can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the default browser of lotus notes :)

File->Settings-> Web browser and change it to default browser of your system.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed comment in Location document, that, in fact, Location document is ignored and you must set preference you mention.

Answer (score 1):

B y the way, have a look here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268588
Lotus Notes 8 is using IE to render the pages. So, if the version of Lotus Notes is 8, then your clients will not have any problems even when using embeeded browser of LN.

Vahagn